# Should mypy infer type from Union options?

Tags: python, mypy, typing

In the following code `fn_int` will only be called with an `int` as an argument, yet `mypy` complains I might be passing it a `str` (viceversa for `fn_str`).

Is there something I'm missing here?
Should/can I somehow narrow down the type before passing arguments to `fn_int` and `fn_str`?

```py
from typing import Union


def fn_int(arg: int) -> None:
    print(arg)


def fn_str(arg: str) -> None:
    print(arg)


def fn(arg: Union[str, int]) -> None:

    if arg in range(4):
        fn_int(arg)
    elif arg == "str":
        fn_str(arg)
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

```py
> mypy mypy_test.py
mypy_test.py:15: error: Argument 1 to "fn_int" has incompatible type "Union[str, int]"; expected "int"  [arg-type]
mypy_test.py:17: error: Argument 1 to "fn_str" has incompatible type "Union[str, int]"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [type narrowing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html), and mypy doesn't do type narrowing for `==` or `in` comparisons. After all, they don't really guarantee type. As a fairly common example, after `x == 3` or `x in range(5)`, x could still be a float rather than an int. (Sure, a standard string won't pass an `in range(4)` check, and a standard int won't pass an `== "str"` check, but you could have a weird subclass.)

mypy will do type narrowing for the following kinds of expressions:

- `isinstance(x, SomeClass)` narrows `x` to `SomeClass`.
- `issubclass(x, SomeClass)` narrows `x` to `Type[SomeClass]`.
- `type(x) is SomeClass` narrows `x` to `SomeClass`.
- `callable(x)` narrows `x` to callable type.

You can also write your own type guards with [`typing.TypeGuard`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html#user-defined-type-guards), and mypy will understand those too.

Answer (score 0):

arg is str or int, but you never check which type it is,
therefore check with `if isinstance(arg, int)`.

then mypy knows that this function is only called if it is of desired type.

**Example**:

```
if isinstance(arg, int):
    fn_int(arg)
elif isinstance(arg, str):
    fn_str(arg)
else:
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: or to preserve the functionality of the code it should be like `if isinstance(arg, int) and arg in range(4):`